# ByteBuffer and put data

Tags: java, android

Why do combinations of two types of bytes array return an empty string of bytes? What am I doing wrong in the code example? Thanks for help

```
ByteBuffer headerData = ByteBuffer.allocate(50);
byte[] totalChunksData;
totalChunksData = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putInt(totalChunks).array();

byte[] checksumData;
checksumData = ByteBuffer.allocate(40).put(shaCheckSum.getBytes()).array();

headerData.put(totalChunksData);
headerData.put(checksumData);

ByteBuffer headerDataBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
byte typeByteData = (byte) 2;
byte lenByteData = (byte) 48;

headerDataBuffer.put(typeByteData);
headerDataBuffer.put(lenByteData);
headerDataBuffer.put(headerData);


headerDataBuffer result:
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

Comment: Looks like you need to `flip()` `headerBufferData` before getting values out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're doing wrong is how you print :-)

```
    ByteBuffer headerData = ByteBuffer.allocate(50);
    byte[] totalChunksData = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putInt(2).array();
    byte[] shaCheckSum = ByteBuffer.allocate(40).put("2".getBytes()).array();
    headerData.put(totalChunksData);
    headerData.put(shaCheckSum);

    ByteBuffer headerDataBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
    byte typeByteData = (byte) 2;
    byte lenByteData = (byte) 48;
    headerDataBuffer.put(typeByteData);
    headerDataBuffer.put(lenByteData);
    headerDataBuffer.put(headerData);

    for (int i = 0; i < headerDataBuffer.limit(); i++) {
        System.out.format("%x ", headerDataBuffer.get(i));
    }
```

then I've got

2 30 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

as expected (48 = 30 hex)